Does Matthew allude to Isaiah 42 in the Sermon on the Mount
I am interested in the seeming parallel between

"You are the light of the world." Matthew 5:14a

and

"I will keep you and will make you to be a covenant for the people and
a light for the Gentiles" Isaiah 42:6b

I come from a tradition where world is taken to mean "all people" and not "the universe", thus the similarity in my mind.
https://www.ligonier.org/learn/articles/what-does-world-mean-john-316
I always thought of this as Matthew referring to the Jews and referencing Isaiah to emphasize their role as a "kingdom of priests, and an holy nation" Exodus 19:6b. Jesus of course refers to himself as this way in John, but that could be Jesus identifying with the fulfillment of the Law. In other words my view is that Matthew is describing the intended role of the people of Israel, and how "the [new] covenant for the people" will lead to the renewal of Israel through the Messiah. Is this view at all supported by the text, or is this view not supported in scripture and tradition? I found nothing on Wikipedia about light of the world referring to the Jews, only Jesus and his disciples, but the article was not particularly long.

I would say "light of the world" referring to the Jews is possible, but don't think this is the case if we take into account the immediate context of Jesus’ teachings:

Matthew 5:11 says: Blessed are you when they revile and persecute you, and say all kinds of evil against you falsely for My sake.

The above scripture indicates that Jesus is currently referring to believers. People who specifically follow him. So, "you are the light of the world" would make more sense as being directed to his followers.
That being said, it's true that Jesus' general audience was Jews and there does seem to be a switch where Jesus begins addressing Jewish people (probably unbelieving) who are living under the law. And what Jesus is going to do in the sermon is: [1]

Jesus is going to show them they don’t even understand how perfect
and holy the law REALLY is
When Jesus gets done pointing out the true stand of the law, every
human being on earth should be realizing how hopeless they are, and
how desperately they need a better covenant founded on a better promise

This is to show how we all need Jesus, forgiveness, the cross, and the promises of being saved, through faith, apart from works of the law.

This does not mean that Matthew was not heavily influenced by Isaiah.
Because they seem to so strongly refer to the person and activity of Jesus Christ, Isaiah's prophecies concerning the Servant are among the most well-known Messianic predictions of the Old Testament.
Allow me to quote much from James Flamming  (Southwestern Journal of Theology Vol. 11 - Fall 1968) in order to extablish the frequent use of Isaiah in Matthew.

Isaiah might be called the prophet for the New Testament. Isaiah is
quoted more than twice as much as any other major prophet and more
than all of the minor prophets combined.




Matthew
Isaiah
Incident




6:6
26:20
Sermon on the Mount: Teaching on Prayer


6:16
58:5
Sermon on the Mount: Teaching on Fasting


5:34
66:1
Sermon on the Mount: Teaching on Oaths


25:35, 36
58:7
Parable of Sheep and Goats




Matthew used Isaiah more extensively in an explicit way than any of
the other Evangelists. The above instances are only from the material
peculiar to his Gospel.


The most obvious use of Isaiah is made by Matthew. It is interesting
to note that Goodspeed begins his little book on Matthew with a
section entitled, “Isaiah in Matthew.” Matthew’s purpose was to show how the life, death, and resurrection of Jesus exactly fulfilled the prophetic utterances of the Old Testament.




Matthew Reference
Isaiah Reference
Quoted Text




Matthew 1:23
Isaiah 7:14
“Behold, a virgin shall conceive and bear a son.”


Matthew 3:3
Isaiah 40:3
“The voice of one crying in the wilderness . . .”


Matthew 4:15, 16
Isaiah 9:1f
“The people who sat in darkness have seen a great light . . .”


Matthew 8:17
Isaiah 53:4
“He took our infirmities and bore our diseases.”


Matthew 11:5
Isaiah 35:5, 6
“The blind receive their sight and the lame walk.”


Matthew 11:23
Isaiah 42:1-4
“Behold, my servant whom I have chosen . . .” (There seems to be a discrepancy here. Probably should be Matthew 12:18.)


Matthew 21:5
Isaiah 62:11
“. . . Behold, your king is coming to you, humble and mounted on an ass . . .”


Matthew 21:13
Isaiah 56:7
“My house shall be called a house of prayer.”


Matthew 24:7, 29, 31
Isaiah 13:10, 19:2, 27:13, 34:4
“For nation will rise against nation . . . the sun will be darkened and the moon will not give its light, and the stars will fall from heaven, and the powers of the heaven will be shaken . . . and he will send out his angels with a loud trumpet call . . .”




I looked up some references to support your view, and indeed this seems the more traditional interpretation than mine. For example Augustine: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Nicene_and_Post-Nicene_Fathers:_Series_I/Volume_VI/Our_Lord%27s_Sermon_on_the_Mount/Book_I/Chapter_6

The situation is a bit more involved.
In the OT we have several references to "Light" as a metaphor of salvation in the LORD, namely:

Ps 27:1 - The LORD is my light and my salvation— whom shall I fear? The LORD is the stronghold of my life— of whom shall I be afraid?
Isa 9:2 - The people walking in darkness have seen a great light; on those living in the land of the shadow of death, a light has dawned.
Isa 42:6 - “I, the LORD, have called you for a righteous purpose, and I will take hold of your hand. I will keep you and appoint you to be a covenant for the people and a light to the nations,
Isa 49:6 - He says: “It is not enough for You to be My Servant, to raise up the tribes of Jacob, and to restore the protected ones of Israel. I will also make You a light for the nations, to bring My salvation to the ends of the earth.”
Isa 51;4 - Pay attention to Me, My people, and listen to Me, My nation; for a law will go out from Me, and My justice will become a light to the nations; I will bring it about quickly.
Isa 58:8 - Then your light will break forth like the dawn, and your healing will come quickly. Your righteousness will go before you, and the glory of the LORD will be your rear guard.
Isa 60:2, 3 - For behold, darkness covers the earth, and thick darkness is over the peoples; but the LORD will rise upon you, and His glory [or "light"] will appear over you. Gentiles will come to your light, and kings to the brightness of your dawn.
Isa 62:1 - For Zion’s sake I will not keep silent, and for Jerusalem’s sake I will not keep still, until her righteousness shines like a bright light, her salvation like a blazing torch.
Micah 7:9 - Because I have sinned against Him, I must endure the rage of the LORD, until He argues my case and executes justice for me. He will bring me into the light; I will see His righteousness.

The NT builds on the OT and continues this same metaphor of "Light" symbolizing salvation in the LORD/Jesus, and sometimes even quotes an OT passage..

Matt 4:16 - the people living in darkness have seen a great light; on those living in the land of the shadow of death, a light has dawned.” [Quoting Isa 9:2]
Matt 5:14-16 - You are the light of the world. A city on a hill cannot be hidden. Neither do people light a lamp and put it under a basket. Instead, they set it on a stand, and it gives light to everyone in the house. In the same way, let your light shine before men, that they may see your good deeds and glorify your Father in heaven.
Luke 2:30-32 - For my eyes have seen Your salvation, which You have prepared in the sight of all people, a light for revelation to the Gentiles, and for glory to Your people Israel.”
John 1:4, 5, 9 - In Him was life, and that life was the light of men. The Light shines in the darkness, and the darkness has not overcome it. ... The true Light who gives light to every man was coming into the world. [This is an allusion to Ps 27:1]
John 3:19 - And this is the verdict: The Light has come into the world, but men loved the darkness rather than the Light because their deeds were evil.
John 8:12 - Once again, Jesus spoke to the people and said, “I am the light of the world. Whoever follows Me will never walk in the darkness, but will have the light of life.” [This is an allusion to Ps 27:1]
John 12:36 - While you have the Light, believe in the Light, so that you may become sons of light.” After Jesus had spoken these things, He went away and was hidden from them.
Acts 13:47 - For this is what the Lord has commanded us: ‘I have made you a light for the Gentiles, to bring salvation to the ends of the earth.’ ” [Quotes Isa 49:6]
Acts 26:23 - that the Christ would suffer, and as the first to rise from the dead, would proclaim light to our people and to the Gentiles.”
2 Cor 4:4 - The god of this age has blinded the minds of unbelievers so they cannot see the light of the gospel of the glory of Christ, who is the image of God.
2 Cor 4:6 - For God, who said, “Let light shine out of darkness,” made His light shine in our hearts to give us the light of the knowledge of the glory of God in the face of Jesus Christ.
Phil 2:15 - so that you may be blameless and pure, children of God without fault in a crooked and perverse generation, in which you shine as lights in the world
1 Peter 2:9 - But you are a chosen people, a royal priesthood, a holy nation, a people for God’s own possession, to proclaim the virtues of Him who called you out of darkness into His marvelous light. [Note: this is a direct allusion to the establishment of the Israelite covenant in Ex 19:5, 6]
1 John 1:7-9 - And this is the message we have heard from Him and announce to you: God is light, and in Him there is no darkness at all. 6If we say we have fellowship with Him yet walk in the darkness, we lie and do not practice the truth. But if we walk in the light as He is in the light, we have fellowship with one another, and the blood of Jesus His Son cleanses us from all sin.
Rev 21:24 - And the nations will walk by its light, and the kings of the earth bring their glory into it.

Now, while some NT verses reference OT verses as documented above, "light" as a metaphor for the good news of God's salvation is quite common throughout the Bible.
There are many more verses that could be quoted.
